# How to (almost) perfectly align a DWG to an SVG?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, autocad

I have an airport map in SVG format that I need to update using a DWG file. Considering that the SVG map has been created using an older version of the DWG I am currently using, I assume that it should be possible to perfectly overlap this 2 files and just update the modified part.

My workflow so far was to load the SVG, file->place the DWG on top, and manually adjust the position of the DWG. It's a good match but not good enough. If get an overlap good enough in one area, then I will have a large offset in another.

I have a GIS background and I could do this alignment there, but I would have to reconstruct the whole SVG for just a couple of lines. In the GIS there is the notion of [georeferencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeferencing), where one image/vector without coordinates, like my DWG here, can be "pulled" to an object that has coordinates, like my SVG map. 
Could I do something similar in Illustrator, for example select 5-6 points on the DWG, like road intersection and snap them to road intersection from SVG and when doing this pulling all the DWG data in it's rightful place?

[image: Example]

Comment: Why not do it in a CAD application? Those applications have way better tools for precise moving, snapping and scaling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recall a method to do multipoint alignment right now but it seems simple:

- With Smart Guides enabled (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) drag a reference point (let's call it point **A**) in your DWG until it snaps to the correspondent point in the SVG;
- Rotate and Scale the DWG using your reference **A** as the center and dragging a second point until it matches the underlying SVG